# OneSignal and GetStream

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

Is there a way we can integrate Chat API with chat information to go to OneSignal to send out pushes?  We already are subscribed to OneSignal and have our user's settings saved there.

I can see only direct connection to APN and Firebase are available.